# What goes first: wp_head or the_content hooks in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I am learning plugins. I just want to increase views after opening the post. If I have these lines commented:

```
//    if(is_single()){
//        $views++;
//    }
```

I don't see any increase. When they are not commented, after opening the post I see the increase immediately.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'get_views_count');
function get_views_count($content){

    if(is_page()){
        return $content;
    }

    global $post;

    $views = $post->my_count;

//    if(is_single()){
//        $views++;
//    }

    return $content . '<p>Views: ' . $views . '</p>';
}


add_action('wp_head', 'increase_counts');
function increase_counts(){

    if(!is_single()){
        return;
    }

    global $wpdb, $post;

    $views = $post->my_count + 1;

    $query = "UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET my_count=$views WHERE ID=$post->ID";
    $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

I thought that wp_head hook should go first than the_content. It is easier to me that logic: wp_head takes the count number from db, increase it and write it to db. Then the_content just output the result. How to know which hook goes first? How could I change their priority in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rachel Vasquez has one of the most complete articles on WordPress' hooks ordered by firing sequence you can find around, so whenever you need to know which hook fires first you should totally check it out: [The WordPress Hooks Firing Sequence!](http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/)

Now, to answer your question, `wp_head` fires first. The problem with your code lies here:

```
global $wpdb, $post;

$views = $post->my_count + 1; // HERE!
```

You're assigning `$views` the current value of `$post->my_count` + 1 (eg. 5 + 1 = 6), but `$post->my_count` still retains its old value (eg. 5).

If you want to display the updated views count, you need to increment `$post->my_count` first:

```
global $wpdb, $post;

$post->my_count = $post->my_count + 1; // Increment the views count in the $post object first
$views = $post->my_count; // Assign the newly updated views count to the $views variable
```

That way, when your `get_views_count()` function gets called the `$post` object has been updated with the correct views count already.

**Aside:**

It seems you have altered the `wp_posts` table to include your `my_count` column. Please, don't do that.

Avoid changing core stuff (database tables and/or WordPress core files and folders) whenever possible to ensure maximum compatibility of any plugins or themes you develop with future WordPress releases. You'll want to store your views data in the `wp_postmeta` table via the [update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) function instead.

Comment: But $post is updated in db after wp_head,  so the_content should get a new value.  Why isn't  the_content updated?